# On click the Link , trigger a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is a part of a slider code.

how to change this code to open a page link, not a lightbox of prettyphoto.

```
if (typeof this.options.map[middle].link_url != 'undefined') {
                this.$prettyPhoto_a.attr('href', this.options.map[middle].link_url);
            } else {
                this.attr('href', '');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location.href` if you are redirecting the page

```
        (typeof this.options.map[middle].link_url != 'undefined') {
            window.location.href = this.options.map[middle].link_url;
        } else {
            this.attr('href', '');
        }
```

**OR**

use `window.open(url,'_blank')` if you want to open a tab with that url

```
        (typeof this.options.map[middle].link_url != 'undefined') {
            window.open(this.options.map[middle].link_url,'_blank');
        } else {
            this.attr('href', '');
        }
```

Comment: your code is automatically redirect to the link,but i want to redirect to link, only link clicked. how to stop auto opening link.

Comment: i added this code. but when it added slider is slider only few times. and then stuck.

Comment: did you check your javascript console for any errors?